# Tkinter window opens as black under anaconda

Tags: python, tkinter, anaconda

I am running anaconda 3.7 on a Mac and wish to use Tkintertools. When I run the following simple tutorial Tkinter script, I get a completely black window. If I use python 2.7, after changing "import tkinter" to "import Tkinter", it works fine, the window and text appears correctly. Any ideas?

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")

        self.label = Label(master, text="This is our first GUI!")
        self.label.pack()

        self.greet_button = Button(master, text="Greet", command=self.greet)
        self.greet_button.pack()

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=master.quit)
        self.close_button.pack()

    def greet(self):
        print("Greetings!")

root = Tk()
root.configure(background='white')
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: (Did you try to select text in that black window? Result?)

Comment: Not possible to select text...it is a completely black window. I note that the label appears correctly as the window title.

Answer (score 0):

There's a known incompatibility issue on Mac between certain versions of Python and of Tcl/Tk. [Here's a bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue35485) where the problem was seen with IDLE, and [here's a description](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/#built-in-8-6-8) on python.org.

In my case, I fixed the problem by downgrading my conda environment's Tk from 8.6.9 to 8.6.8:

```
$ conda install tk=8.6.8
```