# Background wont change tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Im using a mac ,and I have this problem after creating window using `tkinter` its bugs out the background color.
Code example:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Radio-App')
root.geometry("200x200")
root.configure(bg = 'white')

v = StringVar(root, "1")

#dictionary to store values
button_values = {
    "RadioButton 1" : "1",
    "RadioButton 2" : "2",
    "RadioButton 3" : "3",
    "RadioButton 4" : "4",
    "RadioButton 5" : "5"
}
for (text, value) in button_values.items():
    Radiobutton(root,text = text,variable = v,  background = 'light blue').pack(fill = X, ipady =6)

root.mainloop()
```

Window example:
[image: bug example]

Comment: FWIW, your code works fine for me on Monterey, python 3.8.9

Comment: im using 3.10.1

Comment: can't reproduce on Windows 8.1, Python 3.8.2, but I think it is more of an OS issue than Python version issue

Comment: Thats what i think it is unfortunately.

Comment: this seems like a related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54957374/tkinter-window-opens-as-black-under-anaconda

Comment: What if you use `import tkinter` instead of `from tkinter import *` and also place a `tkinter.` before everything that comes from tkinter library?

Comment: So I managed to try this on a different mac with a different os version , and everything is working fine. Thank you for trying to help (:

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
from tkinter import *
gui = Tk(className='Window Color')
gui.geometry("400x200")
gui['bg']='green' #or change to white
gui['bg']='white'
```

Update:
you should add the buttoms like that:

```
button = Button(tkWindow, bg='blue')
button = Button(tkWindow, bg='black')
button = Button(tkWindow, bg='white')
button = Button(tkWindow, bg='red')
```

please check if the commands work for you without the buttons. then add the buttons and check

more reference- https://pythonexamples.org/python-tkinter-window-background-color/

Comment: Still black even without the buttons.

Comment: use only my code

Comment: Iv done it and still black screen.  its a bug but i dont know whats wrong